# Problems in expansion of a setcounter macro (Use of \csname doesn't match its definition)?

Tags: macros, expansion

Followup to [Split the reference counter for any numbered item (like with subequations)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192297/split-the-reference-counter-for-any-numbered-item-like-with-subequations/) : I was trying to make a generic [subanything](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192309/2595) macro, and I fail miserably - see MWE below for what I get as error at, basically, `\setcounter{parent#1}{\value{#1}}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} % \pagecolor
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagecolor{yellow!15}
\usepackage{trace}

% modded from {subequations}, `kpsewhich amsmath.sty`
\newcounter{parentlstlisting}% Counter for ``parent lstlisting''; set up manually for all that may be used in subanything
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subanything}[1][]{%
  \traceon
  \xdef\subanyin{#1}%
  \xdef\dosubany{1}%
  \typeout{subanything: inside '#1'}%
  \ifx#1\undefined%
    \xdef\dosubany{}%
    \typeout{subanything: Didn't get argument: '#1'; skipping start}%
  \else%
    \ifx\subanyin\empty%
      \xdef\dosubany{}%
      \typeout{subanything: Didn't get argument: '#1'; skipping start}%
    \else%
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \typeout{subanything: A}%
    \edef\tcsa{theparent\subanyin}%
    \edef\tcsb{the\subanyin}%
    \expandafter\protected@edef\expandafter\csname\tcsa\endcsname{\expandafter\csname\tcsb\endcsname}%
    \typeout{subanything: B}%
    \edef\tcsc{parent#1}%
    \makeatletter%
    % problem here with setcounter:
    % \csname theparentlstlisting\endcsname ->1
    % ! Use of \csname doesn't match its definition.
    % <argument> c
    %             @parentlstlisting
    % \@ifundefined #1->\expandafter \ifx \csname #1
    %                                               \endcsname \relax \expandafter...
    \expandafter\setcounter\expandafter{\tcsc}{\value{#1}}%
    \setcounter{#1}{0}%
    \typeout{subanything: C}%
    \expandafter\def\csname the\subanyin\endcsname{\expandafter\csname theparent\subanyin\endcsname\alph{#1}}%
    \ignorespaces%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}{%
  \ifx\dosubany\empty% ifx #1: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \endsubanything.: 1
    \typeout{subanything: skipping end}%
  \else%
  \setcounter{\subanyin}{\value{parent\subanyin}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Hello...

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:ex1}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:ex1a}
a = b + c
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:ex1b}
x = y + z
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Ref'ing: master eq.~\ref{eq:ex1};
inner a eq.~\ref{eq:ex1a}, inner b eq.~\ref{eq:ex1b} ...

\begin{subanything}[lstlisting] \label{lst:ex1}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1a,
columns=fixed,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 80484c4: cmd one
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1b,
columns=fullflexible,
% basewidth=\tlen,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 80484c4: cmd one
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{subanything}

Ref'ing:
inner a listing~\ref{lst:ex1a}, inner b listing~\ref{lst:ex1b} ...

\end{document}
```

It looks like it's breaking on the at `@` in `c@parentlstlisting` - which should be absurd, given we're explicitly inside a `\makeatletter`?! What am I missing here?

Comment: If I compile your code (pdflatex, TeXLive 2014), it fails at this line     `\expandafter\protected@edef\expandafter\csname\tcsa\endcsname{\expandafter\csname\tcsb\endcsname}%`, line number 29, and it runs at least syntactically correct if I comment it out

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer - that line is supposed to be `\protected@edef\theparent#1{\the#1}`, but it was giving me problems like that, so I tried to `\expandafter`-it; and I thought it was solved, seeing the error show on `\setcounter` line... will need to take a look again. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the line

```
\expandafter\protected@edef\expandafter\csname\tcsa\endcsname{\expandafter\csname\tcsb\endcsname}%
```

Here, you are expanding `\tcsa` (which you don't actually need to do), but not expanding `\csname` before `\protected@edef`. The result is you redefine `\csname`: a Bad Thing! You need instead

```
\expandafter\protected@edef\csname\tcsa\endcsname{\csname\tcsb\endcsname}%
```

which expands the name first, then does `\protected@edef` with the correct name. I've removed another unneeded (but harmless) `\expandafter` in the definition.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get

```
Use of \csname doesn't match its definition
```

is a clear sign that something has gone wrong in a definition, because it means you have *redefined* `\csname`. This happens in

```
\expandafter\protected@edef\expandafter\csname\tcsa\endcsname{%
  \expandafter\csname\tcsb\endcsname}
```

because the first `\expandafter` expands the second wich expands `\tcsa` and then you end with

```
\protected@edef\csname<expansion of \tcsa\endcsname{%
  \expandafter\csname\tcsb\endcsname}
```

which will indeed redefine `\csname` with a very peculiar parameter text.

This is cured, as Joseph Wright points out, by omitting the second `\expandafter` (and also the third, which really does nothing useful):

```
\expandafter\protected@edef\csname\tcsa\endcsname{\csname\tcsb\endcsname}
```

No other `\expandafter` is needed, just the first one in order to present `\protected@edef` with a symbolic token.

However, there are other problems in your code.

1. `\ifx#1\undefined\fi` is completely wrong; if you want to test for emptyness of the argument, use `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`
2. Several of the definitions you make are useless and, as Joseph Wright remarks, expansion is done in the wrong order.

Finally, the solution is far simpler. Only one “parent subcounter” is necessary, unless you want to be able to nest subcounters. Also, `\setcounter` and `\value` already do expansion of their argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% modded from {subequations}, `kpsewhich amsmath.sty`
\newcounter{parent@@subcounter}% Counter for the parent subcounter

\makeatletter
\newif\if@subanyempty
\newenvironment{subcounter}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \@subanyemptytrue
    \typeout{subcounter: Didn't get argument: '#1'; skipping start}%
  \else
    \def\subany@argument{#1}% for the end part
    \@subanyemptyfalse % actually redundant
    \refstepcounter{#1}% step the given counter
    \protected@edef\theparent@@subcounter{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \setcounter{parent@@subcounter}{\value{#1}}%
    \setcounter{#1}{0}%
    \ifcsname theH#1\endcsname % for hyperref
      \@namedef{theH#1}{\theparent@@subcounter\alph{#1}}%
    \fi
    \@namedef{the#1}{\theparent@@subcounter\alph{#1}}%
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \if@subanyempty
    \typeout{subanything: skipping end}%
  \else
    \setcounter{\subany@argument}{\value{parent@@subcounter}}%
  \fi
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Hello...

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:ex1}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:ex1a}
a = b + c
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:ex1b}
x = y + z
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Ref'ing: master eq.~\ref{eq:ex1};
inner a eq.~\ref{eq:ex1a}, inner b eq.~\ref{eq:ex1b} ...

\begin{subcounter}[lstlisting] \label{lst:ex1}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1a,
columns=fixed,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 80484c4: cmd one
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1b,
columns=fullflexible,
% basewidth=\tlen,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 80484c4: cmd one
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{subcounter}

Ref'ing:
inner a listing~\ref{lst:ex1a}, inner b listing~\ref{lst:ex1b}, master \ref{lst:ex1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an `expl3` version that allows nesting, by defining a “parent” counter the first time the environment is used with a particular counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{subcounter}{o}
 {
  \IfValueT{#1}{ \sdaau_setup_subcounter:n { #1 } }
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {
  \IfValueT{#1}{ \sdaau_restore_subcounter:n { #1 } }
  \ignorespacesafterend
 }

% an expl3 version of \protected@edef
\cs_set_eq:Nc \sdaau_protected_edef:Npn { protected@edef }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sdaau_protected_edef:Npn { c }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sdaau_setup_subcounter:n #1
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cF { c@parent@@#1 }
   {% for the first time a counter is subbed
    \newcounter{ parent@@#1 }
   }
  \refstepcounter{ #1 }
  \sdaau_protected_edef:cpn { theparent@@#1 } { \use:c { the#1 } }
  \setcounter{ parent@@#1 } { \value { #1 } }
  \setcounter{ #1 } { 0 }
  \cs_set:cpn { the#1 }{ \use:c { theparent@@#1 } \alph{#1} }
  \cs_if_exist:cT { theH#1 }
   {
    \cs_set_eq:cc { theH#1 } { the#1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sdaau_restore_subcounter:n #1
 {
  \setcounter{#1}{\value{parent@@#1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Hello...

\begin{subcounter}[equation]\label{eq:ex1}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:ex1a}
a = b + c
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:ex1b}
x = y + z
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subcounter}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Ref'ing: master eq.~\ref{eq:ex1};
inner a eq.~\ref{eq:ex1a}, inner b eq.~\ref{eq:ex1b} ...

\begin{subcounter}[lstlisting] \label{lst:ex1}
%\begin{subcounter}% switch the comments to test
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1a,
columns=fixed,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 80484c4: cmd one
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.325\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
caption={[short] Some instructions here; the font here is \texttt{\ttdefault}.},
escapechar=!,
showlines=true,
label=lst:ex1b,
columns=fullflexible,
% basewidth=\tlen,
frame=tlrb]
080484c4 <list>:
 80484c4: cmd one
 80484c7: cmd two
 80484ca: cmd three, four
 80484cf: cmd five
 80484d6: cmd six, seven
 80484dd: cmd more than enough
 80484e0: cmd  not_even_joking
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{subcounter}

Ref'ing:
inner a listing~\ref{lst:ex1a}, inner b listing~\ref{lst:ex1b}, master \ref{lst:ex1}

\end{document}
```